# scrollview not growing vertically when content size increases beyond screen size

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/notesLayoutManagerScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fffaaa"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context="com.gp.app.professionalpa.layout.manager.NotesLayoutManagerActivity">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/notesLayoutManagerParentLinearLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dip"
        android:background="#ffffff">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
        android:background="#ffffff">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

with the above layout.xml code scroll bar does not appear when the content of the linear layout with ids "linearLayout1" and "linearLayout2" grow in size vertically.

Please suggest how can i bring scrollbar in my activity view when the size of "linearLayout1" and "linearLayout2" grows beyond parent size. I want single scroll bar for my complete activity view and not separate scroll bars for "linearLayout1" and "linearLayout2".

Comment: All layout_height wrap_content?

Comment: What do you mean with *does not appear*?

Comment: @mvai  the linear layouts "linearLayout1" and "linearLayout2" never expands beyond parent height so scrollbar never appears.

Comment: And why should it appear if your linear layouts are not big enough? Give one a very large `height` value, and your scrollbar will be there.

Comment: I am dynamically adding framelayouts(with fragments) into "linearLayout1" and "linearLayout2" and i am expecting when the total size of all the framelayouts increases beyond screen height scrollbar should appear.

Comment: Be sure to tag me to get me notified. What happens if you remove the `android:fillViewport` attribute?

Comment: Apart from that you need to change LinearLayouts' attribute `android:layout_height=` from `"match_parent"` to `"wrap_content"`.

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView should have a layout_height of wrap_content as well.